# How do I change colour of inbuilt toolbar icons in tinymce editor(v 5.1.2)

Tags: css, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm using some of the options provided by tinymce in toolbars like alignLeft, alignRight etc. which will display it in black color. I want to just change the colour of the icon provided with it.

Please let me know how to do it?

P.S. My editor code:

```
 <Editor
     init={{
            selector: "textarea",
            paste_data_images: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,
            plugins: [
              "lists table link image paste help wordcount code autoresize",
            ],
            toolbar:
              "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | image help",

          }}
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with soms css

```
.tox .tox-tbtn svg {
    fill: #ff0000!important;
}
```

Comment: Well, I had used it and using that css with `content_css: "/myLayout.css"`. `myLayout.css` is present in the same folder where I have defined tinymce. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: don't put it in content_css but in your default admin css